# Get notified if a downstream workflow fails

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a collection of GitHub Actions workflows that I centrally manage and are utilized by downstream consumers. This allows me to make updates to the scripts used by other teams without needing to update anyone relying on my scripts. It looks something like this:

```yaml
jobs:
   call-workflow:
      uses: org/repo/.github/workflows/my-action-script.yml@main
```

However I would like to know if this script fails for someone who is using this action. Is this possible?

My workflow scripts, as well as all consuming repos, are all in the same org.

I've combed through the notification docs in GitHub but it seems like notifications will only be sent if I initiated the workflow or possibly if I watch a repo. Since I have a template project which already has these workflows stubbed out it is not necessary for teams to contact me when they want to leverage my scripts so individually watching each repo is not a very viable solution.

Comment: Have you considered including an `if: failure()` step _in the reusable workflow_ that sends a message somewhere. Distinguishing between intended and accidental failures might be tricky though.

Comment: I think that is a very viable idea to the problem.  I was hoping to just configure something in the Github UI instead of maintaining an email alias to send failure notifications to but it wouldn't be the worst thing.

Answer (score 0):

In https://github.com/settings/notifications, there's System > Actions where you can select "On GitHub" and/or "Email", and "Only notify for failed workflows":

[image: Screenshot of config settings]

According to the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/managing-subscriptions-and-notifications-on-github/setting-up-notifications/configuring-notifications#github-actions-notification-options), this alerts for failed workflows on repos you're watching. If you combine that with [automatic watching](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/managing-subscriptions-and-notifications-on-github/setting-up-notifications/configuring-notifications#automatic-watching), which subscribes you to all new repositories if you're an admin, you should get notifications for failing workflows everywhere.

If this is too broad, you could set up a workflow on a schedule that queries all repos to see if they call your reusable workflows, and then use the [watching API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/activity/watching?apiVersion=2022-11-28) to subscribe and start getting notifications.